# Sign & not support in Thymeleaf

Tags: thymeleaf

I wrote this script in my html:

```
<iframe src="http://docs.google.com/gview?url=http://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/web/compressed.tracemonkey-pldi-09.pdf&embedded=true" style="width:600px; height:500px;"></iframe>
```

It is not wokring, but if I remove ***&*** from  **"&embedded"** link. It works.

How can I use ***&*** in my thymeleaf?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

can you replace `&` with `&amp;` and let me know if this worked for you

```
    <iframe src="http://docs.google.com/gview?
url=http://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/web/compressed.tracemonkey-pldi-
09.pdf&amp;embedded=true" style="width:600px; height:500px;"></iframe>
```

Comment: @LayLeangsros Glad that it worked, mark it as resolved if you can